# How to show opened tab window using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to show previous window using javascript. i have two html page like test1.html and test2.html

test1.html

```
 <button id="newWindow">New Window</button>
```

test2.html

```
 <button id="prevPage">ok</button>
```

If i click newWindow button from test1.html it will go to test2.html in new tab window.

If i clcik prevPage button from test2.html page it will close current window tab and should go to the test1.html tab window.

```
     $(document).on('click', '#newWindow', function () { 
     window.open("test2.html"); 
     });

     $(document).on('click', '#prevPage', function () {

     /*close pressent window(test2.html)*/
     window.close();

     /*open the test1.html tab window*/

     window.opener('test1.html','parent').focus();

     });
```

Comment: You could try to save the previous page in localstorage and access to it, as far as I know history API does not provide information of the previous state.

Comment: Hmm, if you use a normal hyperlink instead of `window.open()`, won't the prev url show up in the history API?

Comment: There was a functionality in the past to show current and previous as read only strings, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History but that is obsolete for some cases, and I don't see any standard solution in the api for this case...

Comment: You can see the current with window.location.href but you see I cannot know the string of the past... as requested by OP

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you need to have the first window still open in order to open a new one, otherwise the js function process is lost before that happens. So you should open your new window first, then close the original one. Like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#newWindow', function () { 
    /*open test2.html*/
    window.open('test2.html').focus();

    /*close test1.html*/
    window.close();
});

$(document).on('click', '#prevPage', function () {
    /*open test1.html*/
    window.open('test1.html').focus();

    /*close test2.html*/
    window.close();
});
```

Comment: This is not working in chrome:  self.close();
        var mypreWindow=window.open('test1.html','Start Page');  
           mypreWindow.focus(); 
     $("#transfer_funds").dialog("open");

Comment: You don't need the second parameter in the `window.open` function.

Answer (score 0):

Why not rely on history object and simpy write

```
window.history.back();
```

Comment: Than you would have to open the previouse window first and than close the current window. One question though...Is it completely necessary that you open this new page in a separate window. You could open in in the same window and than back button would work with history.